# Open Port Checker

Tags: internet

I need a software to monitor open ports on my network based on my internet IP address. I've used programs in [here](http://www.mylanviewer.com/) but they scan my LAN. I want to scan my WAN to see which ports are open and which aren't based on my internet IP, not my internal or router's.

**Requirements:**

- must scan *all* ports (not just a subset)
- must work "from the outside" (i.e. scan the WAN interface, not the local network)

It's useful when, for example, you want to check whether Bittorrent, Proxy etc. ports are currently blocked by ISP or not. thanks.

Comment: You would need to call that tool from the outside (e.G. a server you control). Do you have any infrastructure that you can use for this? If so, please specify the operating system of said device.

Comment: There are tons of WebApps that will to that for you, I just searched ["scan open ports online"](https://ixquick.com/do/search?q=scan+open+ports+online) and found some.

Comment: i found them too but they either have some limitations or are not accurate and i just tried them and they show all ports success meaning open, but i still have some kind of problem with protocols. btw, why do i need to do this from outside? is it mandatory? shouldn't i try every port from inside of my network to find out which one is currently open or blocked?

Comment: If you want to know if your ISP is doing the filtering you will need to send a signal through your ISP. Also, "having problems" can be caused by closed ports but does not have to be. If all your ports are open according to the tools, your problem is somewhere else :) It could be that a) you are not forwarding the ports to your machine b) your ISP performs Deep Packet Inspection and lets the TCP SYN through that the port scanners use, but not the actual content that you are expecting. (Or c: something I forgot) A complete analysis would be far beyond the scope of this question, though.

Comment: Apart from the fact that "have some limitations" doesn't correspond with the requirements you've listed (none except "to see which ports are open"). So it's pretty unclear what exactly you're looking for – or, if you don't even know that yourself, "too broad".

Comment: @izzy, i know what i'm looking for and it might seem broad because if i wanted to specifically ask my question, i'd post it somewhere else on this website. by limitations i meant they don't scan all available ports.

Comment: I've edited your question accordingly. It's still missing the OS part. As Angelo already mentioned: the scan must be done from the outside (you can't "scan" from the inside to see whether someone pinned a paper to your door from the outside, right? And you cannot check the door knob on the outside that way either – same with the ports). So either you'd need a web service, or have another machine available "in the outer world". Also be careful with port scans when you're not the owner of the network/machine you're scanning, as it might trigger an "intrusion alert".

Comment: @AngeloFuchs, how can i send a signal through my ISP?

Comment: @Izzy, thanks, the OS i want to run the software on? yes but i really can't make a connection between your examples and my problems. i want to know if the whole access or only some ports related to Open-vpn or SSH protocols have been blocked by my ISP recently. how can a web service from outside of my network find this out?

Comment: I recommend we continue this discussion in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12851/software-recommendations) to avoid extended discussions on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Angelo commented, you need something that scans from the outsize: GRC's [ShieldsUp](https://www.grc.com/shieldsup).

It scans your ports from the outside and tells you if they are open, closed (better) or stealth (best) + advice for first time users, full explanations of your results. Here's the results for scanning my file sharing ports:

[image]

I just used it last weekend to make sure that my SIP ports were not detectable from the outside.

Use the buttons at the bottom of the second page to scan specific port ranges:

[image]

(or specify ports yourself for the bottom two buttons).

---

It also lets you scan for a vulnerability where router manufacturers have set open uPnP to the outside - an absolute no-no.

Comment: thanks, the tools on that website are useful and i just found out that my problem isn't about closed ports.